# Obtaining memory locations of local variables

Tags: binary-analysis, stack-variables, local-variables

For ELF binaries on Linux, if the executable is not stripped, it is possible to recover memory locations of location variables in the form of relative addresses to stack/frame pointer? As an example, if a C program contains an integer variable `var` in function `main`, is there any means to associate its address on stack, say `[rbp-0x18]` to the source variable itself?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start first with finding local variables. Binary files contain multiple sections used for a plethora of purposes. The section of interest in your case is the [*.bss*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss#BSS_in_C). In this sections, you're supposed to find a reference to the local variables used by your program.

Now, regarding the variable name, the only way to associate it to a relative address is through the compiler's debug information ([DWARF2](http://eagercon.com/dwarf/dwarf-2.0.0.pdf)/[DWARF3](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/Dwarf3.pdf) format for ELF binaries), if you use **GCC** with the **-g3** option. You can use **GDB** to extract the information, it parses the dwarf information to associate assembly code lines with source code lines, and memory locations to variable.

You have to know that a variable name is only an abstraction of a memory location which is only known to the compiler at compile time, and after optimizations. Keep in mind that if you push the compiler to optimize (**-Ox** with **GCC**, x = [1, 2, 3, s, fast]), it'll minimize its stack references and use registers instead. Therefore, all references to your local variables will vanish into a temporary use of registers (the registers will be released and used elsewhere).

Note : If you analyze an optimized code using **GDB** you'll notice that some function parameters or variables are shown as *"optimized out"*.

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is possible only if the executable is compiled with debug information (DWARF).
In other cases this information is removed.
[Here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/) you can see an example of how it looks like.